# Как оформить отправляемое эллектронное письмо

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, каким способом оформляются рассылки писем на почту, пробовал HTML тэги, но в почтовике он отображается в исходном HTML формате, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

А далее просто добавляете в тело HTML код письма.

Если городить простыню кода не для вас - попробуйте использовать [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)